# Как перезагрузить службу на удаленной машине?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Management;

namespace WMITest
{
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Username = @"pc1\Administrator";
            options.Password = "123qwe!@#QWE";
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\pc1\root\cimv2", options); 
            scope.Connect();
            Console.WriteLine("connet");

            /* для получения уведомления о завершении операции */
            ManagementOperationObserver Stop = new ManagementOperationObserver();
            Stop.Completed += new CompletedEventHandler(Stop_CallBack);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-------------");
                string NameServices = "Spooler";
                WqlObjectQuery query = new WqlObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service  WHERE Name=\"" + NameServices + "\"");
                ManagementObjectSearcher find = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
                foreach (ManagementObject spooler in find.Get())
                {
                   /* Так работает */
                    spooler.InvokeMethod( "StopService", new object[] { });
                    /* Так не работает выдает ошибку  80070005 - Access is denied  вопрос, почему, что не так*/
                    spooler.InvokeMethod(Stop, "StopService", new object[] { });
                }
                Console.Read();
            } 
            catch (Exception e)  
            {
                // обработка ошибок
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
        static void Stop_CallBack(object sender, CompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           // что то происходит
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx)

Comment: Если служба зависла, ServiceController не поможет